# How do I describe a transformation?

Tags: characters, character-development, fantasy, description

In my story, my main character, a young man named Irian in an industrial human society, is captured, and transformed by merfolk into one of their kind (very standard merfolk, his legs are replaced with a blue scale covered tail with two fins).

My struggle is - this is a very inhuman experience, that I cannot know. How do I effectively describe this, and how something completely alien to me feels?

I guess then I have a bonus question:

- how much is too much description? A big thing now is that this human character is constantly thinking about how weird the sensations of his new lower body are, how much is going to far so that the reader isn't getting annoyed with repetition?

Comment: Your last bonus question is off-topic. We can't tell you how your character should feel, we can only tell you how to write what they're feeling. Your first bonus question, however, is closely related enough to the main question that it can stay.

Comment: @F1Krazy I removed the bonus question.

Comment: This transformation would likely involve changes to the brain as well to enable functionality without years of training,(not to mention respiration). It might not feel weird at all, which could be it's own kind of weird. Unfortunately, I think as an author the description is up to your art.

Comment: Huge tonal difference between a **Stan Lee** transformation, an **HP Lovecraft** transformation, and a **Franz Kafka** transformation…. *Legs replaced with a fishtail* is not a 'universal experience' that an author can evoke through language and description. You will need to look deeper to gain reader empathy. Writing isn't Worldbuilding, don't waste words trying to convince readers this is 'believable'.... You've tagged this question as 'character' and 'character-development'. Start with the theme/message of the story, and develop a character who illustrates that theme through their journey.

Comment: @DWKraus The traditional "Mermaid" swim of a dolphin fin motion is actually utilized in one of the four basic swimming strokes in competative swimming competitions (Specifically the Butterfly Stroke, which uses arms to push you out of the water for air, while the dolphin kick motion propels you... it's definitely the most energy draining of the strokes though so going to a dolphin kick without much training is going to be difficult at locomotion at first (think about how Ariel in the Disney film had trouble with walking).

Comment: One book series to look into for good examples is Animorphs which featured humans turning into animals frequently within one book (to the point that the iconic covers always showed a picture of the book's narrator turning into an animal featured in the story.  The descriptions were always interesting and morphing never occurred the same way twice, even when they were morphing the same animal and most characters had no control over what changes happen in what order.

Comment: @hszmv I mean that the body wouldn't have the internal wiring to interpret the new parts without brain alterations. The brain still perceives lost limbs after they have been removed (phantom limb syndrome), so I'd guess that adding a completely different type of limb to a body would require new wiring, brain centers, and training to use them (or added instincts).

Comment: @DWKraus Yes and no.   The "Dolphin Kick" form of locomotion is not unknown to humans... it just takes skill... the muscles used would be abdominal.  The most likely body restructuring is an elongation of the spine to form a tail and the shrinkage of legs to vestigial limbs (most Whales and Dolphins still have "leg" bones... they just don't protrude from the body and have no muscular development).

Comment: @hszmv even though this question went kaput and all, this was the kind of answer I was looking for. I think the dolphin kick would be more unfamiliar to my character though. He is living in an industrial era society, and though he can swim, it isn't with any very good technique.

Comment: @WasatchWind:  The four basic competative strokes are "Freestyle (AKA Front Crawl, which uses arms to pull your way through water), "Backstroke (Similar to freestyle but done on the back keeping head above water at all times), Breast Stroke (Best described as swimming like a frog... slowest stroke, but very efficient, and translates well to underwater movement).

Comment: This question is about fictional biology,  so it is off topic here and probably on-topic for World building. (It's even similar to an existing question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/30707/22818)

Comment: @Laurel  and... this is the struggle. Put this question on there and they said that it was out of focus and "asking us to write your story." I reworded it to asking how someone should psychologically react to a transformation, and that was still considered a bad question. I feel afraid to ask any questions on these SE sites. It feels like the people on worldbuilding are scared to entertain the notion that someone might like some advice on their writing. 

Then they're like "then go to a writing forum." - a place where I have no chance of someone answering, and they don't have expertise.

Answer (score 3):

These kinds of transformations don't happen in real life, so you are free to make it up any way you want. In existing stories, the transformations happen in different conventional ways:

- in magic stories, the transition is caused by a spell and usually immediate and painless
- in science fiction stories, the transition is done by a medical procdure, the subject is unconscious during it, and the experience is much like any operation (a common add on is the shock at seeing the transition and the psychological repercussions of it)
- in horror stories, the transition is caused by a disease or poison and it is excruciatingly painful (in horror movies you can commonly see the person undergoing the transition writhe on the floor and scream in pain)

Of course you can make up other ways (e.g. peeling away the skin of the legs to reveal the fish skin beneath it).

As you see from my examples, often the genre dictates some aspects of the transition. In romantic fantasy the transition is painless, in horror it is full of pain. In science fiction the procedure is scientific, in fantasy it is magical. In the same way other aspects of your story will dictate the right procedure and experience for you. You need to consider:

- What kind of world does the transition take place in? Is it a magic based world, is it friendly or dark, etc.
- Who does the transition happen to? What kind of person is he? How does the story affect him? What are his goals, who is his antagonist, in what way will the story change him?
- What kind of culture do the merfolk have? Are they animal-like, living naked in the open sea? Are they like humans, building houses under water and using technology? What is their religion? Do they use magic?
- What genre is your story? Horror, Sci Fi, Fantasy, Thriller ...